# Difference between scanning @Configuration classes and @Import configuration classes

Tags: spring

I have been using Spring 3.2+ for some time now, Most of the time I am able to use either of the below options and it works, but I want to know if there is any specific difference.

Here is my JndiConfig java configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class JndiConfig {

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
    BasicDataSource datasource = new BasicDataSource();
    datasource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    datasource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/csdb");
    datasource.setUsername("root");
    datasource.setPassword("root");
    datasource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
    return datasource;
}
}
```

I can use the following options:

**OPTION 1**

```
@Configuration
@Import({JndiConfig.class})
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);

}

}
```

**OPTION 2**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.security"
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);

}

}
```

In the **option 1** I import the `JndiConfig` where as in **option 2** I just do a component scan for `JndiConfig`.

Can anyone explain me the difference between these two?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Right now I can only figure out two differences:

- the obvious one that, by using component scan, you can also pickup other components, not just the configuration class, that might be in the same package. This can lead to importing beans that you might not want, but I find that unlikely
- when using @Import, you have the option of implementing the **ImportAware** interface on the class that gets imported, and this gives you access to the annotation metadata of the importing class, if it is useful to you

Comment: The second point looks to be of some use that I was not aware of. 
Anything else you would like to point out?

Comment: When doing `@Import` you have to know all the configuration classes you need to load. When developing larger application this can be hard, scanning for `@Configuration` classes is then easier and allows for a more component oriented design. (You could do the same with xml files btw).

Comment: For the moment I don't have anything to add